# Infinispan TimeoutException ISPN000476

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

I am experiencing Embedded InfiniSpan cache issue where nodes timeout on re-joining the cluster.

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 7 from vvshost
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.onTimeout(SingleTargetRequest.java:64)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.call(AbstractRequest.java:86)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.call(AbstractRequest.java:21)
```

The only way I can get the node to re-join is to switch off the cache and delete all local cache persistence files.

Here is the configuration which I am using:

**Transport:**

- TransportConfigurationBuilder - defaultClusteredBuild
- JMX Statistics - Enabled
- Duplicate domains - Allowed

**Cache Manager:**

- Manager Class - EmbeddedCacheManager
- Memory - Memory Size: 0
- Persistence: Single File Store
- async: disabled
- Clustering Cache Mode - CacheMode.DIST_SYNC

Comment: Regrettably this is too little information. Ideally you should set up trace logs on both `org.infinispan` and `org.jgroups`, and caputure a dump of stack traces of all threads on the target machine. There you can trace the request and find where it got stuck.

Comment: It'd also be important to know what Infinispan version you are using, which transport (TCP or UDP)...etc. Try out latest Infinispan release if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems right to me, but the value of remote-timeout is "15000" milliseconds by default. Increase the timeout until you stop getting the error.

Hope it helps

Comment: 15s is quite a lot to be honest. I would like to understand whether re-joining takes too long or whether there is some other issue. But I will try.

Comment: let me know what happens.